# Discord py - Get current guild id in background task

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

So with my code, I want to print a message to the console if the current guild id is the same as a specific guild id. The bot should check that for every server that is listed in the database.

And thats my code:

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=15.0)
async def topic():
            print("topic start")
            mydb = getConnection()
            mycursor = mydb.cursor()
            mycursor.execute(f"SELECT * FROM partner_list")
            myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
            for x in myresult:
                try:
                    x1 = [x]
                    guild = bot.get_guild(int(x1[0][0]))
                    name = (str(x1[0][1]))
                    print("inside try catch")
                    print(guild.id)
                    print(ctx.guild.id) # <--- This doesn't work
                    if int(ctx.guild.id) == int(guild.id):
                        print("Trading Sucht")
                        #mydb.commit()
                except:
                    pass
            mycursor.close()
            mydb.close()
```

The error is that ctx.guild.id is not working, because he can't find "ctx". Is there any other way to let the bot go through each guildid row from my database and check if the current guild id is the same as the one from the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to extract the `guild id` and this can be done by creating another command.

## I am assuming that this bot is for a single server.

#### 1. Create an empty list:

```
guild_id = []
```

#### 2. Create a command list this:

```
async def func():
    for guild in client.guilds:
        id = guild.id
        print(id) # As your BOT is in one single server, only one ID would be extracted and this can be used.
        guild_id.append(id)
```

### Now you can use the ID in the list wherever you want to. :D

This is you can solve it. Please feel free to ask anything if you still get this error. :)

Thank You! :D

Comment: I got `TypeError: topic() missing 1 required positional argument: 'ctx'`

I use `topic.start()` in the `on_ready` event.

Comment: Oops! I am making some changes in the answer. Please do check them.

Comment: Answer Edited! @Overdrive

Comment: Welcome! :D glad to help!